# Fancybox requires jQuery 1.3+, found 1.2.6. Error in drupal

Tags: jquery, drupal, jquery-plugins, fancybox

I am using fancybox module for image display in drupal 6. and while changing the setting i got this error.

```
 Fancybox requires jQuery 1.3+, found 1.2.6
```

and they are asking for packed version. and from Jquery v-1.3 there is no packed version available. Can anybody tell me how to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to pack the js code yourself

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/01/minimize-and-pack-your-javascript-code.html

Comment: can u tell me how to use it.. Any tutorial or something like that.. I am new to drupal.

Comment: Not really a Drupal expert but somewhere you should be able to tell which version of jquery you want to use (masterpage?) if you have the possibility to use your own local copy, otherwise we're in trouble ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked into the jQuery Update module?

> This module facilitates an upgrade of
>   jQuery in Drupal core and allows other
>   contrib modules to rely on a newer
>   jQuery version.
>
> "Stock" Drupal 6.x: 
> jQuery 1.2.x 
>   (Drupal 6.2 and below: 1.2.3, Drupal
>   6.3 and above: 1.2.6) 
> jQuery Update 6.x-1.x: jQuery 1.2.x (currently 1.2.6) 
> jQuery Update 6.x-2.x: jQuery 1.3.x (currently 1.3.2)

http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update